# z-index not working, positioning one div above another

Tags: z-index

In this page http://qelma.mediadrive.fr/jedonnemonavis.php I am trying to position the div written "pourquoi" above the div with blue border. For some reason the blue div seems to be always on top. Any idea ?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `position: relative` and `background: #fff` to `#page2 .textbox > div.label` seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: You are genius Mash ... :)